# ServiceStack HTTP Utils

Tags: servicestack, restsharp

I’ve to make a post request to a service (not implemented with ServiceStack). From the docs, please correct me if I am wrong, I have to use HTTPUtils nuget package (v. 6.0.2), but if I make a request using its extensions the service returns a 400 bad request.
The same request done using RestSharp (v.105.0) works. 
However, I noticed that I had to use an old version compared to the available version of RestSharp.(nothing changes if I downgrade ServiceStack).
Could it be that the service implementation is not compatible with the latest versions of RestSharp and ServiceStack?
Is it correct to use HTTPUtils for a service that I don't know if it's implemented with ServiceStack? 
Does ServiceStack add some extra wrapper to the .NET framework HTTP client? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the docs for ServiceStack's [HTTP Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) which can be used for calling generic HTTP APIs, which are extension methods in the [ServiceStack.Text](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text) NuGet package.

Receiving a **400 Bad Request** response suggests that you're sending an invalid request.

Whenever you're investigating issues calling HTTP APIs you should be inspecting the HTTP Traffic with a HTTP tool like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) so you can verify that it's sending the HTTP Request you want to send, whilst [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) is a useful tool for quickly working out the HTTP Request you want to send.

If you want help with using a tool you'll need to post the C# source code you're  using, the HTTP Request/Response it's sending and the HTTP Request you want to send. Typically the HTTP Response should contain information on why your request is invalid.